# Laravel View - improve readability

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used if conditions in the `href` and in `a` block.

How would you make the code cleaner for readability?

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-complete" href="/settings/statuses/{{$status->id}}/@if ($status->enabled == 0) enable @else disable @endif">
  @if ($status->enabled == 0) Enable @else Disable @endif
</a>
```

Comment: Perhaps make a URL property (through an accessor maybe) on your `$status` object. `href="{{$status->toggleUrl}}"`

Comment: @BenSwinburne I think that mean I would have to go through the $status loop in a repo or model and add a href link

Comment: If `$status` refers to an eloquent model, you can use an accessor (https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to generate a property on the fly.

Comment: BTW, is that logic right? When `enabled` is `0` you show "Enable"? Seems backward to me.

Comment: @bishop I would assume if `enabled` is false (0), you want to give the user the option to enable it. If `enabled` is true (1), you want to give the user the option to disable it.

Comment: @patricus Oh, this is a status change, not a status display. Gotcha, thanks!

Comment: It's looking like what you need is something generic for multiple classes of objects and is relatively easy on the eye in views. I think a combination of my plus @BenSwinburne answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that status is a model (although you could put it on whatever it is which has a status).

```
// app/Traits/HasToggleableStatus.php
trait HasToggleableStatus
{
  public function getStatusToggleUrlAttribute()
  {
    $action = $this->enabled ? 'enable' : 'disable';

    return url("settings/statuses/{$this->id}/{$action}");
  }
}

// Customer.php
use App\Traits\HasToggleableStatus;

class Customer extends Eloquent
{
  use HasToggleableStatus;

  protected $appends = ['statusToggleUrl'];
}

// Markup in view
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-complete"
  href="{{$status->statusToggleUrl}}">
  {{ $status->enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable' }}
</a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it global somehow? Some model will also have enabled/disable - for example `$customer->enabled`

Comment: Write the functionality into a trait, or a base controller. I'll add a trait example.

Answer (score 1):

Necessarily a subjective answer, and personally I am a fan of micro-views, so I might define a sub-view that accepts an object that be able to have its status changed.

```
// status-display.blade.php
@if ($object instanceof StatusInterface)
    @if ($object->enabled)
      Disable
    @else
      Enable
    @endif
@else
    Unknown
@endif

// foo.blade.php
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-complete" href="/settings/statuses/{{$status->id}}/">
    @include('status-display', [ 'object' => $status ])
</a>

// bar.blade.php
@include('status-display', [ 'object' => $customer ])
```

Has the advantage of allowing single-point change for display associated with the "status" of the thing, as well as mixing-and-matching where this status display appears in the layout. (I.e, you might not only want it in an `<a>`, but maybe also a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

Comment: That is really good idea, but `$status` (from model) name could be vary but the logic are the same Enable/Disable. For example I might have customer model which also contain `$customer->enabled` - how would you do that?

Comment: I'd have the class implement an `interface` that indicates its got the `enabled` trait, then you can pass anything that supports that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operations " ? : " instead of conventional if else statements. refer following chagnes i had replaced if else with ternary operators.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm text-complete" href="/settings/statuses/{{$status->id}}/{{$status->enabled == 0 ?  enable : disable }}">
{{$status->enabled == 0 ?  enable : disable }}
</a>
```